# book recommendation for trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, book-recommendation

I know that
$$\cos \theta = \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$$
$$\sin \theta = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$$

I am not sure if it was addition or subtraction. I forgot those formula. I was trying to derive it.

$$\cos^2 (\theta)+\sin^2 (\theta)=1$$
$$\cos^2(\theta)=-\sin^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$\cos^2(\theta)=\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$$

But, I know that $$-\sin^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2})\not= \sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)$$

I saw some weird equations also.

$$2\cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} = 1-\cos \theta$$
$$2\sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2} = 1-\cos \theta$$

Could you suggest me a book (PDF) which I could use for practicing double/half angle formula? Which book should I follow for trigonometry?

Comment: Surely instead of the $1$ in $\sin^2(\frac\pi{2} - 1)$ you meant $\theta$ right? Anyway the actual way I would suggest you do this would be to start from the sum and difference formulas.

Comment: The most fundamental proof of the first two formulas is to draw a right triangle and recall the geometric definitions of sine and cosine.

Comment: @GregMartin That slipped my mind, thanks for mentioning that

Comment: @GregMartin Could you suggest me a book, pls?

Comment: Mathematics by RD Sharma Class XI https://drive.google.com/drive/mobile/folders/1NwSZVQAxCV4lla7KrGL2xu3q3Q4nkyN0                              Look for chapter 5 Trigonometric Functions.     Subsequent chapters will cover Double/ Triple angle formulae etc.

Comment: The book [Trigonometry](https://www.amazon.com/Trigonometry-I-M-Gelfand/dp/0817639144/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8) by I. M. Gelfand and Mark Saul is a good resource.

Comment: Part III of [Elementary Trigonometry](http://www.knowledge-dojo.com/papers/1927%20Elementary%20Trigonometry%20-%20Durell%20&%20Wright.pdf) by Durell and Wright.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your book recommendation, here is one:

[image]